# Mysterious Data loss after compressing SDE database

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, c#, enterprise-geodatabase

I suffer sometimes from data loss in SDE database exactly after compressing database.

i mean by data loss that some data remains in its prior state before edits, but this problem do not affect the totality of the data, it may touch just a portion of a feature class , and it may not touch all the feature classes.

i have made the compressing script to take edits data in priority.

i remarked also problems when i try to close to application that i'm using for editing, when i make some edits it takes too much time to close after i close it with close (X) button,so in the most cases i kill the process with task manager. i wonder if in this time the Arcobjects or Arcsde make some back up for edits. may be this is the cause for the Data loss.

i still wonder if this problem is the cause of this data loss.

**My question :**

why my app take so long time to close after i've made some edits ?

i'm available for any additional informations.

I'm using Arcgis 10.1 , VS 2010 , C#

Comment: Can you define the nature of your "data loss"?  Why does your question have nothing to do with the title? (Please update the question)

Comment: Your SDE database has multiple issues, and if you value your data, you should get in touch with ESRI support ASAP, instead of asking here.

Answer (score 3):

things to try

1. check the compress log to see if the compresses are successful
2. Do a complete database analyze after every compress
3. Compress down to 0 state by deleting all your versions and, if necessary unregistering your data as versioned. This includes removing any replicas. Then check there is no data in the delta table
4. If you are using custom code to make your edits please make sure you handle edit sessions and edit operations correctly
5. Rec and post versions before exiting out of your app.